# Problem with CSS

Tags: html, css

Am a newbie in CSS and am writting this code and the main content and the sidebar are falling out of place. Anyone know why?

Here is the HTML and CSS used

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <title> WEB HELPDESK</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/polaris.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="header">
        <p class="banner"> WEB HELP DESK <p>
      </div>

      <div id="pathway">

      </div> <!-- pathway -->

      <div id="main">
        <div id="menu_bar">
          <div class="menu">
            <ul>
              <li> <a href=""> Manufacturers </a> </li>
              <li> <a href=""> Add Manufacturer </a> </li>
              <li> <a href=""> Edit manufacturer </a> </li>
              <li> <a href=""> Delete Manufacturer </a> </li>              
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li> <a href=""> Asset types </a> </li>
              <li> <a href=""> Add Asset types </a> </li>
              <li> <a href=""> Edit Asset Types </a> </li>
              <li> <a href=""> Delete Asset Types </a> </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li> <a href=""> Asset Status </a> </li>
              <li> <a href=""> Add Asset Status </a> </li>
              <li> <a href=""> Edit Asset Status </a> </li>
              <li> <a href=""> Delete Asset Status </a> </li>              
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li> <a href=""> Assets  </a> </li>
              <li> <a href=""> Add Asset  </a> </li>
              <li> <a href=""> Edit Asset  </a> </li>
              <li> <a href=""> Delete Asset  </a> </li>              
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- Menu bar -->
        <div id="sidebar">
          sidebar
        </div> <!-- Menu bar -->

        <div id="main_content">
          <div id="errors">

          </div> <!-- Errors -->

          <div id="content">
            content goes here

          </div> <!-- Content -->
          am floating here
        </div>
      </div> <!-- Main -->

      <div id="footer">

      </div> <!-- Footer -->
    </div> <!-- Container-->

  </body> <!-- Body -->
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: arial, san serif;
  color: #000000;
}

#container {
  margin: 0em 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid #46A5E0;
}

#header{
  margin: 0.1em 0em 0.1em 0.1em;
  border: 1px solid #46A5E0;
  width: 99%;
  height: 5em;

}

#header .banner {
  color: #333399;
  text-align: centre;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

#pathway {

}

#main {
  margin: 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#menu_bar {
  margin: 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em;
  border: 1px solid #46A5E0;
  width: 13em;
}

#menu_bar .menu {
  font-size: 0.7em;
}

#sidebar {
  margin: 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em;
  border: 1px solid #46A5E0;
  float: right;
  width: 13em;
}

#main_content {
  margin: 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em;
  border: 1px solid #46A5E0;
  float: right;
}

#errors {

}

#content {

}

#footer {

}
```

Comment: i'm guessing here, but are you trying to a three column layout here with a header and footer div?

Comment: Even I have a same question .. and as per my answer .. its better to switch to "table" architecture .. than taking pain to use so ... many DIV tags ..

Comment: The correct medical term is 'divitis'.

Comment: Other issue: you are using the wrong doctype. Switch to the XHTML Strict doctype.

Answer (score 3):

Check the [Holy Grail article from A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail). The article shows the best way to create a 3 column layout.

Don't go the easy path and just use tables for your layout! Use the `table` tag only for "real tables", for everything else use divs, spans, lists, etc.

The benefit of a table-less layout is mostly that it's more accessible: An older browser, or a mobile browser, will simply ignore the CSS and display only the HTML-contents of the page. Div tags will be ignored, while a table would clutter your layout... It's true, there will be LOTS of divs! But using tables for layouting isn't necessary anymore these days!

Also, personally, I wouldn't start with a WYSIWYG tool. If you want clean HTML you will have to write it yourself. Also, with a little practice, you will write HTML faster by hand than with a tool. All the professional layouters I have worked with write HTML in plain text...

Answer (score 0):

Your sidebar is floated right; the main content isn't. Try moving the sidebar above the main content in the markup. Alternatively, try specifying a float for the main content as well.

Answer (score 0):

Go with a float:left for the left resting div tags with float right for the right side div, I suspect you are just missing the float parts.

Answer (score 0):

not sure exactly what you're trying to get to, but I suspect something like...

replace the following css class definitions: #menu_bar, #main_content, #footer with

```
#footer {
 clear:both;
}

#main_content {
 margin: 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em;
 border: 1px solid #46A5E0;
 float: left;
}

#menu_bar {
 margin: 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em;
 border: 1px solid #46A5E0;
 width: 13em;
 float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What was required was a div within the  at the end indicated as

that would have the following property in CSS

## clear {

```
clear: both;
```

}

this would solve the positioning problem, it will bring the sidebar and the main_content to the right positions and from here adjustments can be made to the sidebar and main_content in terms of width and margins